# Upsert into Mongo based on date?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

```
obj = {
  date: 137097408891,
  id: '1234',
  value: 'value'
}
```

What I want to do it apply the `value` field to the object with the id, only if the date is newer then the current one saved. If no document with that ID is saved, just save this one.

I'm using node-mongodb-native. Is there a way to do this without first getting the document checking the date and saving it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given object `o`

```
db.collection.update( { id:o.id, date: { $lt:o.date } }, {$set : { o }}, {upsert:true} );
```

This is assuming there is a unique index on `id`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I was thinking this but I thought it would try to insert a new document if the saved one was newer.

Comment: it will, but it will fail since unique constraint on id will be violated which is what you want :)

Comment: why does this throw, `Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback`?

Comment: it calls back the err for inserting the same id, should i just disregard it?

Comment: exactly. you might want to verify the type of error - since you don't want to inadvertently disregard a different error from the same operation...